# How to queue Angular router navigations

Tags: angular, typescript, router

I am using a service to add or remove query params as such:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RoutingService {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  addQueryParams(params: Params): void {
     this._router.navigate([], {
       relativeTo: this._activatedRoute,
       queryParams: params,
       queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
     });
  }

  removeQueryParam(name: string): void {
    this._router.navigate([], {
       relativeTo: this._activatedRoute,
       queryParams: {
         [name]: null,
       },
       queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
     });
  }
}
```

This works as expected, but it can happen that the simultaneous invocation of the class's methods cancels an active navigation if the router has not yet finished navigating.
To prevent this, I need a way to create a queue for router navigations.

I have tried to add a field with an array of navigation jobs and listen to router events but I'm not quite sure how I can tie it all together.

Comment: And do you want to handle navigations that has been canceled ? Anyhow, using a queue sounds like the way to go

Comment: I want to prevent that navigations are canceled/overriden. Thats why I want to queue said navigations - I‘m just not sure when/how to trigger the next navigation in the queue safely.

Comment: when navigationStart set a flag isNavigating = true, at any moment, if that flag is still on, you know the request is on going, discard any further nav